# How to merge duplicates in an array of objects and sum a specific property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects:

```
var arr = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        contributions: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        contributions: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        contributions: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        contributions: 1
    }
];
```

... and I want to merge duplicates but sum their contributions. The result would be like the following:

```
var arr = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        contributions: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        contributions: 5
    }
];
```

How could I achieve that with JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lr84keqy/

Comment: In my case, `cosnt res = new Set(array1, array2)` works perfect.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use a hash table and generate a new array with the sums, you need.

```js
var arr = [{ name: 'John', contributions: 2 }, { name: 'Mary', contributions: 4 }, { name: 'John', contributions: 1 }, { name: 'Mary', contributions: 1 }],
    result = [];

arr.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.name]) {
        this[a.name] = { name: a.name, contributions: 0 };
        result.push(this[a.name]);
    }
    this[a.name].contributions += a.contributions;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can use the brand new ES6 Map object : `var result = new Map();
arr.forEach((element) => {
  if (result.get(element.name))  result.set(element.name, result.get(element.name) + element.contributions);
  else  result.set(element.name, element.contributions);
});

console.log(result);`

Comment: Reduce: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lr84keqy/

Comment: @mplungjan I liked your approach

Comment: @mplungjan it worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this using linq framework which is provided by linq.js

here is my code using linq.js and this is nearly look like sql statement.

```js
var arr = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        contributions: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        contributions: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        contributions: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        contributions: 1
    }
];


var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(arr)
        .GroupBy("$.name", null,
                 function (key, g) {
                     return {
                       name: key,
                       contributions: g.Sum("$.contributions")
                     }
        })
        .ToArray();

console.log(aggregatedObject);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```