# Get the sum of matching object in vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have an array with few objects. I want to create a new array with sum of matching object.

```
var array = [
        {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
        {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
        {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
        {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
        {bill_no:444,paid:10 },
        {bill_no:555,paid:12 },
      ]
```

I want the ouput like

```
 {bill_no:123,paid:60},{bill_no:345,paid:24},{bill_no:555,paid:12}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: Can we please get little bit more information on the part "New array with sum of matching object". Does this mean you want to add bill1 and bill2 and return the paid price?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge duplicates in an array of objects and sum a specific property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294781/how-to-merge-duplicates-in-an-array-of-objects-and-sum-a-specific-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to do something like this:

```js
var arr = [
        {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
        {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
        {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
        {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
        {bill_no:444,paid:10 },
        {bill_no:555,paid:12 },
      ]

var sum = arr.reduce((a, obj) => {
  let i = a.findIndex(o => o.bill_no == obj.bill_no);
  i == (-1) ? a.push(obj) : (a[i].paid += obj.paid);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` with `find()` operation inside the `reduce()`:

```js
var array = [
    {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
    {bill_no:123,paid:30 },
    {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
    {bill_no:345,paid:12 },
    {bill_no:444,paid:10 },
    {bill_no:555,paid:12 },
];
var res = array.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  var existObj = acc.find(item => item.bill_no === obj.bill_no);
  if(existObj){
    existObj.paid += obj.paid;
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```